# Sort array based on status of the object and add index only to APPROVED objects?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Problem Statement:
Whenever we try to edit any approved object, it will go to pending status like 'description' in below example. I want the sorted array if duplicates exist and index should be incremented only to the approved objects.

Example
Here is the input:

```
  {
    name: "Akash",
    description: "desc_change",
    status: "PENDING",
  },
  {
    name: "Hari",
    description: "desc",
    status: "PENDING",
  },
  {
    name: "Akash",
    description: "desc",
    status: "APPROVED",
  },
  {
    name: "Priya",
    description: "desc",
    status: "APPROVED",
  },
  {
    name: "Krish",
    description: "desc",
    status: "PENDING",
  },
  {
    name: "Priya",
    description: "desc_change",
    status: "PENDING",
  },
];
```

So, here I Need something like below:

```
  {
    name: "Priya",
    description: "desc",
    status: "APPROVED",
    index: "1",
  },
  {
    name: "Priya",
    description: "desc_change",
    status: "PENDING",
  },
  {
    name: "Akash",
    description: "desc",
    status: "APPROVED",
    index: "2",
  },
  {
    name: "Akash",
    description: "desc_change",
    status: "PENDING",
  },
  {
    name: "Krish",
    description: "desc",
    status: "PENDING",
  },
  {
    name: "Hari",
    description: "desc",
    status: "PENDING",
  },
];
```

So, the expected UI should be like below:(Only the APPROVED status row should have the incremented index)

```
Index | Name | Status  |
------| ---- | ------- |
1     | Priya| APPROVED|
      | Priya| PENDING |
2     | Akash| APPROVED|
      | Akash| PENDING |
      | Krish| PENDING |
      | Hari | PENDING |
```

Comment: Can you clarify?  Sorting by status means that same statuses would be adjacent in the output.  approved, pending, approved is not sorted by status.

Comment: Please clarify your criterion a little. Your array should be sorted on what critera? What do you mean with *like 'description' below*? What is 'description'? When is an element a duplicate? etc...

Answer (score -1):

To restate the problem, I think the OP aims to sort first by name, then by status; then, for some statuses, insert a property relating to the status count.

This code accomplishes that, though it's worth reading the note at the bottom....

```js
function compareDatum(a, b) {
  let nameCompare = a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  return nameCompare ? nameCompare :  a.status.localeCompare(b.status);
}

let data = [{
    name: "Akash",
    description: "desc_change",
    status: "PENDING",
  },
  {
    name: "Hari",
    description: "desc",
    status: "PENDING",
  },
  {
    name: "Akash",
    description: "desc",
    status: "APPROVED",
  },
  {
    name: "Priya",
    description: "desc",
    status: "APPROVED",
  },
  {
    name: "Krish",
    description: "desc",
    status: "PENDING",
  },
  {
    name: "Priya",
    description: "desc_change",
    status: "PENDING",
  }
];

// sort according to the two criteria
data.sort(compareDatum)

// for approved status, assign a counter
let approvedCounter = 1;
data = data.map(el => {
  return el.status === 'APPROVED' ? { ...el, index: approvedCounter++ } : el;
})

console.log(data)
```

**Note** that we depend on the fact that status "APPROVED" sorts lexically before "PENDING". Back in the day, we'd say this violates a rule against "cuteness".  A more principled sort would explicitly state the sort relationship between discrete status values, something like this...

```
function compareStatus(a, b) {
  const statusValues = { APPROVED: 0, PENDING: 1, SOMEOTHERKIND: 2 };
  return statusValues[a] - statusValues[b];
}

// and then the compare function
function compareDatum(a, b) {
  let nameCompare = a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  return nameCompare ? nameCompare : compareStatus(a.status, b.status);
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked @user16614304.  Please mark it correct.  Not sure why it was downvoted